# ¿Cómo mostrarlos datos de SQL Server en un listbox a partir de una selección de un combobox en C#?

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms

La aplicación consiste en mostrar datos de una BBDD de SQL Server donde hay dos tablas: una de alumnos y otra de notas que están vinculadas por el Id de los alumnos. En un Windows Form hay un combobox que muestra los alumnos y quiero que me muestre en un listbox las notas asociadas al alumno seleccionado. He conseguido que muestre los datos en el listbox a partir de la primera selección del combobox pero al cambiar la selección del combobox no cambian los datos asociados del nuevo alumno seleccionado en el combobox:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se observa al cambiar el alumno no muestra las notas asociadas al nuevo alumno sino que sigue mostrando las del primero. El código que he utilizado es el siguiente:

```
public partial class AgregarNotas : Form
{
    SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("server = DESKTOP-B1MVQBF; database = Formacion; integrated security = true");

    public AgregarNotas()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AgregarNotas_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MuestraAlumnos();

        MuestraNotas();
    }

    private void MuestraAlumnos()
    {
        conexion.Open();

        string consulta = "select IdAlumnos, concat(IdAlumnos, ' - ', NombreAlumno, ' - ', ApellidoAlumno, ' - ', TlfAlumno, ' - ', EmailAlumno, ' - ', BajaAlumno) as info from Alumnos where bajaAlumno = 0;";

        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(consulta, conexion);

        SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);

        DataTable tablaAlumnos = new DataTable();

        adaptador.Fill(tablaAlumnos);

        cbxAddNotas.DataSource = tablaAlumnos;

        cbxAddNotas.DisplayMember = "info";

        cbxAddNotas.ValueMember = "IdAlumnos";

        conexion.Close();
    }

    private void MuestraNotas()
    {
        conexion.Open();

        string consulta = "select Nota from Notas where IdAlumno = @Id;";

        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(consulta, conexion);

        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Convert.ToInt32(cbxAddNotas.SelectedValue));

        SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(comando);

        DataTable tablaAlumnos = new DataTable();

        adaptador.Fill(tablaAlumnos);

        ltbNotaAlumno.DataSource = tablaAlumnos;

        ltbNotaAlumno.DisplayMember = "Nota";

        conexion.Close();
    }
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que al cambiar de alumno en el combobox me muestre las notas asociadas a ese alumno en el listbox para luego poder selecionarlas y editar las notas posteriormente?

Añado por si es de interés como son las tablas de la base de datos de SQL Server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si al añadir el evento de SelectedIndexChanged al combobox y aplicar el método `MuestraNotas()` dentro
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
private void cbxAddNotas_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MuestraNotas();
}
```

se obtiene la siguiente excepción:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Paca comprobar que cbxAddNotas.SelectecValue no estuviera vacía o sin valor he creado una varible:

```
    int prueba = (int)cbxAddNotas.SelectedValue;

    label1.Text = prueba.ToString();
```

Cuando en el combobox selecciono al alumno con Id 2 en el label aparece el número 2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando cambio en el combobox al alumno 3 en el label sigue apareciendo el número 2. Con lo cual debe ser un problema relacionado al cambiar en el combobox.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El combo tiene una propiedad en sus eventos de change ahi lo puedes poner, para que cada que cambie se dispare lo que te interesa

Comment: ¿Sería SelectedIndexChanged y aplicarlo al load?

Comment: si cuando le des doble click ahi lo pondrias

Comment: He aplicado el doble click y he metido el método que quiero que se aplique en ese evente y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Podrias editar tu pregunta y enseñarme como quedo

Comment: Ya está editada con la excepción que me sale y lo que he realizado. Anteriormente no me salían excepciones pero no me actualizaba el listbox.

Comment: verifica que cbxAddNotas.SelectedValue no este vacio antes de tratar de llenar la lista...

Comment: debe de ser que cuando llenas el combo la primera vez se dispara lo que tienes que hacer es como dice @gbianchi validar que no este vacio o que si tenga un valor y ya con eso no te deberia de marcar error igual le puedes poner un try para que falle pero la segunda vez que cambies veras como funciona

Comment: llevo muy poco tiempo programando y la verdad es que no se como validar que no este vacío el combobox.selectedvalue. Yo enteindo que si estuviese vacio entonces no me devolveria las notas del primer alumno. ¿que debo hacer para comprobar lo que decís @gbianchi

Comment: combobox.selectedvalue no debe ser null ni una cadena vacia.. solamente eso...

Comment: os muestro en la edición de la preguntalo que he hecho para comprobar si el combobox.SelectedValue estba con un valor pero no cambia al cambiar el alumno el en combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si haces doble click al combobox en el apartado de diseño del form te genera el código de un evento de tipo SelectedIndexChanged.

Dentro del mismo introduces el siguiente código:

```
private void cbxAddNotas_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbxAddNotas.SelectedIndex > 0) MuestraNotas();

    else if (cbxAddNotas.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        conexion.Close(); // Sin este cierre de conexión salta una excepción.

        MuestraNotas();
    }
}
```

El condicional if comprueba cuando cambia el índice de la selección del combobox y ejecuta tu función MuestraNotas().

El condicional else if sirve para el momento en el que cargas el formulario, donde se registra un cambio de índice que por defecto es 0. El cierre de la conexión es necesario para que no salte un error, pero no se exactamente lo que lo origina.

Espero te sirva de ayuda, un saludo.